# What can I do to this expression to lose the summations?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

I'm at the end of a past paper question and need to derive this answer:

[image]

I am very close and have got to this by doing d/dx to the * equation:

[image]

What can I do to get rid of these summation signs and h?

*I have also been told that

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. What is $J_n$, for starters?

Comment: Well if the equality holds, then w.l.o.g you can move the term on the right to the left and fulfill the condition that the entire sum is zero, for all $n$. Your statement at the top is then true for all $n$.

Comment: @JackM Those are [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for any fixed $x$, you have the power series in $h$:
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty h^n\left(J_{n+1}(x)-J_{n-1}(x)+2\frac{\mathrm{d}J_n}{\mathrm{d}x}(x)\right)=0\tag{1}
$$
Thus, we have that for each $n$,
$$
J_{n+1}(x)-J_{n-1}(x)+2\frac{\mathrm{d}J_n}{\mathrm{d}x}(x)=0\tag{2}
$$
which is your desired equation.

Comment: Because it's a power series in $h$ which is identically equal to $0$, therefore all its coefficients must be $0$?

Comment: that's great thank you!

Comment: @JackM: yes. As long as two power series converge to the same function in an annulus around the origin ($a\lt|h|\lt b$), they are the same.